# 'LAB' object has no attribute 'audioFilePath'

Tags: python, oop, pyaudio, python-object

I have a problem with this code:

```
class LAB:
    def __int__(self):
        self.r = sr.Recognizer()
        self.audioFilePath = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Music\\WAV\\male.wav'

    def test(self):
        with sr.AudioFile(self.audioFilePath) as sourceFile:
            audio = self.r.record(sourceFile)
        try:
            print("sourceFile contains: " + self.r.recognize_google(audio))
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("problem raised")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Assistant = LAB()
    Assistant.test()
```

when i run it:

```
  File "D:/Assistant/myLab.py", line 20, in <module>
    Assistant.test()
  File "D:/Assistant/myLab.py", line 10, in test
    with sr.AudioFile(self.audioFilePath) as sourceFile:
AttributeError: 'LAB' object has no attribute 'audioFilePath'
```

what is the solution?
I tried to write the above code without using OOP and it worked fine with me.

Comment: `__int__` should be `__init__`

Comment: ooooh, thanks!!! I didn't see that omg thank you a lot, you saved my day!!